# -bash: /etc/bash.bashrc: Permission denied I have no name

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I have a Debian Wheezy server running, and a test-backup was just run - However, it went the other way! I cleaned it up the best I could, but I'm getting a VERY annoying error now.

Root login is disabled via SSH. The user has to log in as a regular user, then execute `su` to get Root access. When I log in as my user, I get the following message:

```
-bash: /etc/bash.bashrc: Permission denied
I have no name!@server:~$
```

When I execute aa `whoami`:

```
$ whoami
whoami: cannot find name for user ID 1000
```

Checking my `/etc/passwd` file, those user IDs do exist! The permissions on `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `/etc/passwd` are 644, owned by `root:root`. Checking on another server, the `/etc/bash.bashrc` files match up the same, no changes required.

There is the silver lining in that I can `su` into the root user, and access what I need, but I shouldn't need to do this. I cannot find any relevant log entries under `/var/log`, as they just show the successful login attempts (`auth.log`), but no errors. **What can I do to allow the regular users to login again?** Below is an exert of my `/etc/passwd` file, showing that the user ID 1000 exists:

```
lbarone:x:1000:1000:Luke Barone,,,:/home/lbarone:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this is all local auth and no directory services involved (ie, LDAP or NIS)?

Comment: @MaQleod correct, local authentication only

Comment: Is you `nsswitch.conf` set up correctly? There should be a line with `passwd: files` or `passwd: compat`.

Comment: It has `passwd:         compat` just like on another working server

Comment: permissions on `/etc/bash.bashrc`? On which filesystem does it reside? Any strange mount options for it? Does the output of `id -G` prints the correct group ids? - and for the "i have no name" - run `hostname` command and/or check file `/etc/hostname`

Comment: And another thing to check would be `ldd $(which bash)` and verify that all the dynamic libraries can be found and have the right permissions

Comment: 644, Ext4, no weird mount options, hostname is normal. When executing `id -n`, it outputs `id: cannot print only names or real IDs in default format`. The `ldd` one lists only 5 files, all with links with 777 permissions

Comment: Could you pass your `/etc/passwd` through `od -c` to check for any weird characters? Clutching at straws here but you never know.

Comment: @terdon Nope, the only 2-character items are `\n` for the new lines

Comment: As your non-root user, can you `cat /etc/passwd`? Also, do you have SELinux or some other security layer enabled?

Comment: @derobert `$ cat /etc/passwd
cat: /etc/passwd: Permission denied`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to read `/etc/bash.bashrc` (and `/etc/password`) the permissions on the parent directories matter, too. In particular, you need `+x` on them. In your case (from the [chat conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15756035#15756035)) it turns out somehow the permissions on `/etc` were wrong.

The inability to read `/etc/passwd` is why `bash` and `whoami` can't find your username.

Debian's default for `/etc` is 0755; so `chmod 0755 /etc` (as root) will fix at least that immediate problem. You should also investigate how that happened, to determine if there might be other directories with incorrect permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The permission of `/etc/passwd` should be 644. Mine was at 640 due to which I got the **`I have no name!**@mybox:/home$`**

As soon as I `chmod 644 /etc/passwd` as root. That fixed the problem for me.